# Is it possible to run a build in browserify/babel against a certain browser target?

Tags: javascript, browserify, babeljs, gulp-babel

Looking at tables such as these:
http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/

It looks like Chrome is really close to supporting a lot of ES6, meaning (in my mind) that I should be able to drop the following during development:

```
var babelifyOptions = {
    presets: ['es2015', 'stage-0', 'react'],
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
};
```

when using browserify:

```
browserify(browserifyOptions)
    .transform(babelify.configure(babelifyOptions))
    .bundle()
    .pipe(source('app.js'))
    .pipe(buffer())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/js'));
```

And with that hopefully speeding up build times. When building to production, obviously transpilation is still required.

However, when I drop out es2015 presets, browserify chokes on the build, not understanding things like `...`. This makes sense, but is it possible to run browserify while targeting Chrome only? (ie allowing token/operators/features that Chrome currently understands).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think `browserify` is the issue but your version of NodeJS is. I think NodeJS 6 was the first one to support a lot of the ES2015 features by default but notably it does not support the new ES module system. There are a few Babel presets that patch around the things that are missing. Here is just a list of the ones I found in a quick search:

- [`babel-preset-es2015-node6`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-preset-es2015-node6)
- [`babel-preset-node6`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-preset-node6)
- [`babel-preset-es2015-node`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-preset-es2015-node)
- [`babel-preset-es6-node6`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-preset-es6-node6)

Note: I've not used any of them so I cannot make a recommendation for you.

Comment: The module part isn't a big issue, as chrome doesn't support it either. I'm running Node6.3.1

Comment: What output do you get from the following? `node --version; echo "const letters = ['a', 'b', 'c']; console.log(...letters)" | node`

Comment: Thanks for looking at this. I get the following: `v6.3.1 a b c` (across two lines)

Comment: I tried to make a minimal test case for you over at https://gist.github.com/casr/1800d30be83f77bef5e3a36c1ff78c21 . Try putting `package.json` and `index.js` into the same directory. The run `npm install && npm run build`. If it works you should see some `browserify`-style output in your terminal. You could try adjusting the versions of the libraries to see if that trips something up.

Comment: Ah I see, so you still run babel, just without any presets/plugins. Testing now

Comment: Hmm, very interesting, I can run it without the -t babelify switch and it compiles. So something, somewhere is getting caught

Comment: `ParseError: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module'`  Basically getting snagged on the import stuff. But, with these modifications I can get it running with, only the module plugin - which is the desired behaviour https://gist.github.com/cjke/f910b3a7132c58f786c80e6413079066